# PHP more efficient autoloading

Tags: php, autoload

I currently have this

```
class SPL_Load {

    public function __construct() {
        spl_autoload_register('self::loader');
    }

    static public function loader($className) {
        $filename = str_replace('\\', '/', $className) . '.php';
        $filename = str_replace('MVC/', '', $filename);
        if(file_exists($filename)) {
            require($filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Which is called by

```
new SPL_Load;
```

in my index.php file, both classes are declared in the same file - I wonder if there's a way to get it so that I can move this

```
spl_autoload_register('self::loader');
```

function into this process to remove the need for the `__construct()` method in the SPL_Load class

What I mean is something like this

```
spl_autoload_register('new SPL_Load::loader');
```

to replace the SPL_Load construct function and make the reference more efficient in terms of amount of code, although I have no idea if this is even possible/where to begin.

Any ideas would be brilliant thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loader'))
```

remove static in "loader" function

Comment: Will that allow me to reference that method from another class though? EDIT: Actually, that doesn't matter, since it's only one method I can just move the method over into my index class rather than having a whole separate object for one method. 

Thanks man!